# dart doc for libary, why is the main function not documented?

Tags: dart, dartdoc

Hi i have build a blockchain and would like to document the api endpoints written in the main function now i have used dart doc to generate a documentation but it exludes the main function, does anyone know how to include it?
https://github.com/ketuf/gladiato.rs

Comment: Generally the `main` function isn't expected to be called programmatically.  If you want to document command-line arguments and to provide usage instructions for your program, it would be better to put that in your package's `README.md`.

Answer (score 0):

See Github issue here: https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/3096. Currently, nothing in `/lib/src` can have documentation generated for it because it is considered a private library. You can export specific files to a library in `/lib`, which means documentation will be generated for those: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages.

> Directly under lib, the main library file, shelf.dart, exports API
> from several files in lib/src. To avoid exposing more API than
> intended—and to give developers an overview of the entire public API
> of the package—shelf.dart uses show to specify exactly which symbols
> to export:
>
> ```dart
>     export 'src/cascade.dart' show Cascade;
>     export 'src/handler.dart' show Handler;
>     export 'src/hijack_exception.dart' show HijackException;
>     export 'src/middleware.dart' show Middleware, createMiddleware;
>     export 'src/middleware/add_chunked_encoding.dart' show addChunkedEncoding;
>     export 'src/middleware/logger.dart' show logRequests;
>     export 'src/middleware_extensions.dart' show MiddlewareExtensions;
>     export 'src/pipeline.dart' show Pipeline;
>     export 'src/request.dart' show Request;
>     export 'src/response.dart' show Response;
>     export 'src/server.dart' show Server;
>     export 'src/server_handler.dart' show ServerHandler;
> ```